# bytes32 doesn't accept input

Tags: solidity, bytes32

I don't understand what should input into bid() function. Whatever I do, it shows the same error:

```
"Error encoding arguments: Error: invalid arrayify value (argument="value", value="1 true secret", code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=bytes/5.0.5)
"
```

What am I missing?
Below is the code for the bid() function.

```
function bid(bytes32 _blindedBid)
        public
        payable
        onlyBefore(biddingEnd)
    {
        bids[msg.sender].push(Bid({
            blindedBid: _blindedBid,
            deposit: msg.value
        }));
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

When declaring a bytes32 type, this forces you to input a value with a fixed length of bytes32. Since your input (in Remix) is shorter, it returns an error.

I haven't seen your struct & mapping declaration, but I am assuming you have the following code:

```
contract Test {

   struct Bid {
       bytes32 blindedBid;
       uint256 deposit;
   }

   mapping(address => Bid[]) public bids;
 
   function bid(bytes32 _blindedBid)
        public
        payable
    {
        bids[msg.sender].push(Bid({
            blindedBid: _blindedBid,
            deposit: msg.value
        }));
    }
}
```

Therefore, if you add an entry with bytes32 such as:

`0x6c00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000`

the function call should work fine. So with Remix, it's a bit tricky to add this kind of data input and you have to do the conversion *manually*. On the other hand, if you are using a front-end with web3.js, you may use conversions such as:

```
web3.utils.padRight(web3.utils.fromAscii('hello'), 34)
```

Comment: Thanks. I do use Remix to see how different things work. I was confused because it was supposed to have 3 arguments somehow. Here is the link to the example of the BlindAuction contract https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.1/solidity-by-example.html

Answer (score 0):

In my case, for my frontend app, I had to use

`web3.utils.padRight(web3.utils.fromAscii('hello'), 64)`